# Add sort by "my votes"

Tags: feature-request, voting, sorting

In my daily routine I sometimes find myself **re-visit questions** I've already read.

When there are **multiple answers** (and approaches to solve something), I remind myself what was **my chosen answer** in my previews research by scrolling down until I see an upvoted answer by my user.

I would like to suggest a **new sorting tab** called `my votes` which will sort the answers by current user's votes + upvotes as secondary sort

I find it very useful in Stack Overflow but this may fit in all Stack Exchange's sub Q&A sites.

> for instance:
>
> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: banner]

I wrote a

### Chrome Extension

It's called **Upvotes First for StackOverflow** and available on the [Chrome Extension store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/upvote-first-for-stackove/jafbgebfjkfejghbdeohaadmfghkmjlo).

- 100% free and [open source](https://github.com/lets-hack-stuff/stackoverflow-upvote-first/)
- you're welcome to fork and PR with support for additional browsers
- click to watch the [demo on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHF-wiVDUSM)

#### [Install Upvote First for StackOverflow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/upvote-first-for-stackove/jafbgebfjkfejghbdeohaadmfghkmjlo)

---

#### Demo

[image: video tutorial]

(click to watch on YouTube)